# How can I structure bash code to make it easier to track conditionals?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, if-statement, wizard

I am making a install wizard, however I have alot of IF Statements, and it keeps confusing me and I get disorientated, Especially when I try to fix something that's wrong with my Script. How to prevent this? Here's my script:

As you can see I have alot if IF Statements. And I can't keep track of them all. Is there a way to like mark or minimize them, like with HTML?
I'm using the Atom Text editor.

Or is there a way to reduce the IF Statements?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: GlitchyShadowZ

# Name: NJDTL Install Wizard 1.0

# Date of Last Update:

# Date of LEGACY (Initial Release):
clear
echo "Would you like to start the NJDTL Install Wizard? [y/n]"
read startYN
if [ $startYN == y ]
  then
      echo "Starting Install Wizard. . ."
      mkdir ~/.NJDTL
    fi
    if [ $startYN == n ]
      then
          echo "Are you sure you want to cancel the Install Wizard? [y/n]"
          read CancelConfirm
          if [ $CancelConfirm == y ]
            then
                echo "Cancelling Install. . ."
                exit
              fi
          if [ $CancelConfirm == n ]
            then
                echo "Chose "n". Continuing Installation. . ."
                exec $0
        fi
      fi

[Loading Screen removed for the purpose of this post]

if ! [ -d ~/sbin ]
then
echo "A Bin folder in /home/ is required for this program. Create one? [y/n]"
read BinChoice
  if [ $BinChoice = y ]
    then
      mkdir ~/testbin
    fi
    if [ $BinChoice = n ]
  then
    echo "Without a Bin Folder NJDTL Will not work. Cancelling Install."
  fi

else
  echo "bin folder existent. Continuing Install. . ."
fi
fi
```

Comment: You should probably fix your indenting. Try to put the `fi` on the same margin as the `if` it'll help you better keep track of your `ifs`. But there is also `elif` which you can use to cut down on the number of your `if` statements

Comment: Don't use `==` with `[`; either use `=`, or switch to `[[`. Use shellcheck.net to check your code.

Comment: BTW, building an installer to have a whole bunch of prompts that display conditionally after it's running is unfortunate -- it makes that installer hard to automate. Consider accepting either environment variables or command-line arguments, so someone could run `createBin=1 batch=1 ./yourInstaller` or `./yourInstaller --createBin --batch` in a script (or from an automated tool like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc) and not have it prompt at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common use of conditionals is to put the next keyword on the same line:

```
if [ $startYN == y ]; then
  ...
```

`$startYN == n` should be in an elif statement (and the same for `$CancelConfirm == n`):

```
if [ "$startYN" == y ]; then
  ...
elif [ "$startYN" == n ]; then
  ..
fi
```

A case block is usually much more readable when matching 3 or more values and in some cases 2 or more:

```
case "$startYN" in
  'y')
    ...
    ;;
  'n')
    ...
    case "$CancelConfirm" in
      'y')
        ...
        ;;
      'n')
        ...
        ;;
    esac
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `=` and `==` are inconsistently used here. The former is guaranteed to be available in all POSIX-compliant implementations of `test` or `[`, whereas the latter is not.

Comment: (...so, by editing to use `==` only, you've gone with the **less** portable option).

Comment: True. I was trying to be consistent with the question. `=` is probably more readable also in this case.